# Why does the ".on(<event>, function())" style of jQuery event handler not work for "hover"?

Tags: jquery, event-handling

Both of these `.hover(function() {...}, function() {...})` using either the element ID or `this` work:

```
$( "#imgPostTravel" ).hover(function() {
        $('#imgPostTravel').addClass('popout_image');
        $('#imgPostTravel').addClass('shadow');
    }, function() {
        $('#imgPostTravel').removeClass('popout_image');
        $('#imgPostTravel').removeClass('shadow');
});

$( "#imgPostTravel" ).hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('popout_image');
        $(this).addClass('shadow');
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('popout_image');
        $(this).removeClass('shadow');
});
```

...whereas using `.on( "hover", function() {...}`:

```
$( "#imgPostTravel" ).on( "hover", function() {
        $('#imgPostTravel').addClass('popout_image');
        $('#imgPostTravel').addClass('shadow');
    }, function() {
        $('#imgPostTravel').removeClass('popout_image');
        $('#imgPostTravel').removeClass('shadow');
});
```

...does not.

Why not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `hover` is not an event name. Prior to jQuery 1.9 the library supported using this name, as is stated in the "*Additional notes* [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> Deprecated in jQuery 1.8, removed in 1.9: The name "hover" used as a shorthand for the string "mouseenter mouseleave". It attaches a single event handler for those two events, and the handler must examine event.type to determine whether the event is mouseenter or mouseleave. Do not confuse the "hover" pseudo-event-name with the .hover() method, which accepts one or two functions.

Since it's not a standard event name, and the "special case support" that once existed is gone, it simply doesn't work...

Answer (score -1):

I guess you are using the `on` method because you are adding the element dynamically.

Try with the following:

```
$(document).on( "mouseenter", "#imgPostTravel", function() {
    $('#imgPostTravel').addClass('popout_image');
    $('#imgPostTravel').addClass('shadow');
}, function() {
    $('#imgPostTravel').removeClass('popout_image');
    $('#imgPostTravel').removeClass('shadow');
});
```

Where `document` should actually be the closest non-dynamically generated parent to the `imgPostTravel` element.

**UPDATE:**

As it was pointed in another of the answers, `hover` shouldn't be used and `mouseover` or `mouseenter` (depending on the desired functionality) should be used instead.

Comment: No, the element is not added dynamically; I just read that the "on" method is slightly more "performant" and so wanted to try it out. It works for me on "click" just fine.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon that performance difference is so insignificant it's not even worth considering. Internally shorthand methods like `click()` use `on()` so it is an extra function call but unless you could trigger 1000's at a time it really wouldn't matter